# Idiomatic phrase

Tags: idioms

What's the meaning of

> ARE THE BLOODY COCKS STILL RUNNING THE COOP?

Quote from the movie "Young Guns II"

For those who are not native English speakers (85% of the world) these kind of phrases are almost unintelligible.

Comment: Is the phrase still a problem after looking up what coop (and possibly cock - it's not just a penis!) mean(s)? If so, where is the problem?

Comment: I am not a native English speaker and it makes perfect sense to me

Answer (score 3):

I don't know anything about the film but 'cocks' are male chickens (or some other birds), and a 'coop' is a chicken run (enclosure), usually made of wire netting. So could it be an aggressive feminist statement: 'are the bloody men still in charge'?